# How to set default icon in NET DLL?

Tags: .net, vb.net, dll, icons

I have managed a VB.NET ClassLibrary project and compiled it as DLL.

The problem is, this dll is a plugin for a Win32 program, which can display main icon of DLL.
Looks like this icon is recognized by the program as a resource named MAINICON (for c++ example, this described in .rc resource file like that: MAINICON ICON "dllicon.ico" ).

Is there any way to simulate this behavior in .NET DLL?

P.S: I've tried adding icons as MAINICON named embedded resource, but it doesn't recognizes. 
It just displays [this default icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRKa4.png) (have no idea why).

P.P.S: Also I get this clue (not sure will it help or not), but don't know how to use it:

> The program will default to the lowest-numbered icon in its resources.

Comment: Have you tried property page of a project in Visual Studio?

Comment: Yes, but default icon is disabled for ClassLibrary project type - http://i.imgur.com/hyM0MJr.png

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly you have an aplication that accesses a DLL, and you want the aplkication and the DLL to use the same icon, which is that of the application. I have the exact same use case.

The very first line of my code is

```
GetType(Form).GetField("defaultIcon", BindingFlags.NonPublic Or BindingFlags.[Static]).SetValue(Nothing, My.Resources.ThisAppsIcon)
```

This assumes you've stored the default icon in Resources as ThisAppsIcon

I ripped this off SO a few months ago but didn't store the URL in the comments so I can't attribute. Apologies to OP.

I have commented this line of code as

'Pure evil

Comment: Sorry, I will clarify things better once more: DLL is a plugin for win32 app. This app can show a list of installed plugins (with icons if available, recognized as MAINICON resource). I just would like to know how to build my Dll to have resource icon listed there. So far it is not recognized by app.

Comment: Maybe one would suggest another method for embedding resources into .net dll or some dirty tricks... just cannot understand why c++ rc "mainicon" resource is recognized well, but .net resource is not...

Comment: So I gave up trying and just replaced icons manually in resource editor (Resource Tuner 2 solved this problem perfectly).